# Custom Radio Button images dont work in php but they work in html

Tags: php, html, css, radio-button

[image]
As shown in the picture above its working without  issues in html, but when switching to php it wont work as shown in picture below..

[image]

Code: HTML/PHP

```
<label>
              <input type="radio" name="test" value="big">
              <img src="assets/icon-paper.svg" width="150">
            </label>
```

Code: CSS

```
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type=radio] + img {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 91px;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type=radio]:checked + img {
  outline: 0.6px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "switching to PHP" exactly? What specifically has changed? All you've shown is some HTML and CSS code. The rendering is done by your browser based on the HTML and CSS provided...it never interacts with the PHP code. All I can think is maybe you've somehow done something which stopped the CSS from loading correctly. Have you done any investigation e.g. using your browser's element inspector and/or network tools?

Comment: I do not change anything just the file extension yet it doesn't work.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense by itself. Something else must have gone on as well. Open your browser's Developer Tools and then load the .php page. Then firstly use the network inspector to see if the CSS file loads correctly with a 200 ok status.

Comment: Yes, CSS file loads without any issue.
https://prnt.sc/H5zwsmpn1X1t

Comment: Ok so now use the element inspector to see what rules are actually being applied to the element, and whether it's what you expected. Compare with your old copy, if you still have it

Comment: can you post you entire code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/re0mgc6L/ is the closest we can get based on the code you've shown, and it seems to be ok? Not sure if the gap on the left is intentional or not.